# why is my background image for header did not work?

Tags: html, css, background-image

[image]

this is my first HTML project and here iam trying to put background image for the #nheader id but when i toggle the cod the browser tells me it can not load i did not know the reason?

```
<html>

<!--this is the

 start html file-->
<head>
    <meta keywords="html, laern, teach"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title> this is a website </title>
</head>

<body>
   <div id="wrap">
     <div id="nheader">
       <h1>how to write html5</h1>
       <img src="..my demo/images/body.jpg">
     </div>
     <div id="npara">
       <p class="text_para">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <span class="color">consectetur</span> adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad 
       </p>
      </div>

       <div id="footer">
       <p class="text_para">
       this is footer
       </p>
       </div>

    </div>


</body>

<!--here ends th html file -->
</html>
```

Comment: `..my demo/images/body.jpg` is not a valid path should be `../my demo/images/body.jpg` probably but it depends on your setup. Also avoid using spaces in paths

Comment: A shining example for why the HTML and CSS validators play an important part in every web page creation.

Comment: thanks dear, Rob for your comment ,
 i already changed the path as you told me above but it is the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Your image does not work because the path to it is incorrect. Paths can be:

- **absolute paths** (they work irrespective of where they are called from) `http://example.com/images/body.jpg`
- **relative paths**

  - to current script: (i.e. `./images/body.jpg`, `../../images/body.jpg`)
  - to current domain/machine: (i.e. `/images/body.jpg`, `~/img/logo-free.png` )

For more on how paths work on different systems consider reading Wiki: [Path (computing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)).

Remember any server (domain) is, in fact, hosted on a machine (computer) and, therefore, its folder structure is accessible (with limitations pertaining to web) via its path system.

The vast majority of web domains are hosted on Linux (Unix shell systems).